# Throwing Exception causes MVC application to stop

Tags: error-handling

I am using Asp.Net MVC and want to use BusinessException class to include business exceptions into the response of the apis.

I inherited a DomainService for one of my aggregate root.

```
public class FairManager : DomainService
{
    private readonly IFairRepository _fairRepository;
    private readonly IGuidGenerator _guidGenerator;
    private readonly IObjectMapper _objectMapper;

    public FairManager(
        IFairRepository fairRepository,
        IGuidGenerator guidGenerator,
        IObjectMapper objectMapper
        )
    {
        _fairRepository = fairRepository;
        _guidGenerator = guidGenerator;
        _objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
    public async Task<ParticipantDto> UpdateParticipantAsync(Guid fairId, ParticipantDto participant)
    {
        var fair = await _fairRepository.GetAsync(fairId);

        var participantFound = fair.Participants.Where(f => f.Id == participant.Id).SingleOrDefault();


        if (participantFound == null)
        {
            throw new BusinessException(BusinessErrors.PARTICIPANT_CANNOT_BE_FOUND.ToErrorString());
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(participant.Name))
        {
            throw new BusinessException(BusinessErrors.NAME_CANNOT_BE_NULL.ToErrorString());
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(participant.Description))
        {
            throw new BusinessException(BusinessErrors.DESCRIPTION_CANNOT_BE_NULL.ToErrorString());
        }

        participantFound.SetName(participant.Name);
        participantFound.SetDescription(participant.Description);

        return _objectMapper.Map<Participant, ParticipantDto>(participantFound);
    }
```

When code hits the line where BusinessException is thrown, visual studio is stopped and swagger does not show the response. Instead it gives below message

[image: Swagger Error]

When there is no business exception, everything works perfectly.

I also added below service configuration but nothing changed.

```
    Configure<AbpExceptionHandlingOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SendExceptionsDetailsToClients = true;
        options.SendStackTraceToClients = false;
    });
```

Project I am using is the standard MySQL and non-tiered template with MVC UI which i created with below CLI commands.

```
abp new Acme.BookStore -dbms MySQL -csf
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason of this behaviour.
In the Service class I mistakenly put void as a return type of the async method. I changed it to Task and it is working fine now

I changed this

```
public async void AddParticipantAsync(Guid fairId, ParticipantDto participant)
{
    await _fairManager.AddParticipantAsync(fairId, participant);

}
```

to this

```
public async Task AddParticipantAsync(Guid fairId, ParticipantDto participant)
{
    await _fairManager.AddParticipantAsync(fairId, participant);

}
```

Comment: That's totally different code from your question..

Comment: How is that related to `BusinessException`?

Comment: As MVC application was halting when any BusinessException is thrown, I was suspicious that it could be related with Exception flow of ABP framework. But as I noted, the problem was actually related with return type of the service method. So in the end you are right it was not related with BusinessExceptions.

Comment: Then please delete your question as it is incoherent and misleading to future readers.